# BasicHttpBinding with Certificate authentication - error "forbidden"?

Tags: wcf, web-services

I'm trying go get WCF server and client mutually authenticate each other using SSL certificates on transport level using BasicHttpBinding. Here's how the server is getting created:

```
var soapBinding = new BasicHttpBinding() { Namespace = "http://test.com" };
soapBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
soapBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType =
    HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
var sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), uri);
sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), soapBinding, "");
sh.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(
    StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, 
    X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "localhost");
sh.Open();
```

Here's the client:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
var service = new ServiceReference2.Service1Client(binding,
    new EndpointAddress("https://localhost:801/Service1"));

service.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
    StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, 
    X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "localhost");

service.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.
    CertificateValidationMode =
        System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.PeerTrust;

service.HelloWorld();
```

Certificate for localhost is in Personal, Trusted Root and Trusted 3rd Party containers. Internet Explorer can connect to host and see WSDL. Also, SSL calls work fine with ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None

HelloWorld() fails with:

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException occurred<br/>
  Message="The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication
  scheme 'Anonymous'."
```

which is a rethrown exception from: "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

how does one go around figuring out wtf is going on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try adding this in the client just after setting `Security.Mode`:

```
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
```

Comment: I can't believe it was so easy and I didn't catch it :(

Comment: I have the same problem but where the app.config has:
 <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="">
in the transport element :-(

Comment: I'm trying to solve a similar problem - I just tried your code but "add service reference" didn't work on the client. I don't suppose you could attach your whole solution?

Answer (score 2):

If you use standard generated proxy class you can to set transport client credential type to `Certificate` in `App.Config`:

```
<binding name="SpoDataServiceSoap">
    <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"></transport>
    </security>
</binding>
```

C#

```
var client = new MyServiceSoapClient()
X509Certificate2 cert = CertificateHelper.GetClientCertificate();
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert;
```