# WCF - The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'

Tags: wcf, web-services, wcf-security

I know this is a very common scenario, but I've still, after two days of searching, not found a solution to this problem.

I've got a WCF Service and a client (web site), using SSL and a client certificate.

Relevant service config section:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="HOLBinding">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="HOLServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceCredentials>
            <clientCertificate>
        <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine" />
        </clientCertificate>
          </serviceCredentials>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
<services>
      <service name="HOL.Core.Service.HOLService" behaviorConfiguration="HOLServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="bh" bindingConfiguration="HOLBinding" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="HOL.Core.Service.IHOLService" />
        <endpoint address="wb" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehaviour" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="HOL.Core.Service.IHOLService" />
      </service>
    </services>
```

Relevant client service config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="HOLServiceEndpointBehaviour">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" 
                   findValue="mythumbprint" 
                               x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" storeName="TrustedPeople" />

            <serviceCertificate>
               <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust"/>
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IHOLService" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000">
            <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
         </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://www.myhttpsite.co.uk/Service/HOLService.svc/bh" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IHOLService" contract="HOLCoreService.IHOLService" 
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IHOLService" behaviorConfiguration="HOLServiceEndpointBehaviour">
    </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

My certificate is being found, so that's not the problem (took me a day to fix that problem too!)

I believe the error is that the client calling the WCF Service simply isn't sending through the correct details to authenticate... but why?

Comment: First, it may help to [enable WCF tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.100).aspx) on both the client and the service to see what messages are getting sent & recieved. Next, I'd check the account the client is running under to ensure it has access to the certificate that's been installed on the client machine. Lastly, try using [WcfTestClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364(v=vs.100).aspx) in the service environment to ensure the service can be called successfully from a client with access to the certificate.

Comment: Thanks @Sixto Saez - I'll take a look at the access rights to the certificate. I enabled tracing, but couldn't find any specific errors there. Can you see no other setting in my config that would stop the application working, such as lack of dns identity in my endpoint tag (I saw this somewhere, but couldn't get it to work)?

Comment: In fact,how do I check the account the client is running under - do you mean the application pool in IIS? I tried this through ApplicationPoolIdentity and LocalSystem, both to no effect.

Comment: Actually, the permissions to check are on the client side. If you can login with the client credentials on the client machine, check what certs are visible using those credentials. This [SO question & answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731379/basichttpbinding-with-certificate-authentication-error-forbidden) seem to echo your situation. At least, you can use the code to try to troubleshoot from the client machine. Also, this [post gives a good overview of using certs with `basicHttpBinding`](http://www.remondo.net/using-ssl-transport-security-wcf-basichttpbinding/)

Comment: I followed the second link's tutorial, section for section, and still I get the same error and have no idea why. The certification can be seen by the client as I've debugged in Visual Studio on the client box, and the service (.svc) can be accessed on the box, but not externally (403 forbidden). This is becoming a nightmare!

Comment: Just to eliminate other issues, try turning off the security by setting the `mode` attribute to "none" in both the client and the service. Also remove any certificate elements in the config. Have the client call the service. If its successful then its definitely a cert config issue. Look at this [MSDN post on configuring SSL for WCF.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556232.aspx) Your environment is not using a self-signed cert but the process should be very similar.

Comment: I got it working, as best as I could really, I set the certificate settings to "Accept" instead of "Require" in IIS and it started to work. Not sure if this is the best approach, but I tried everything I could find on the web, with no joy.